# Printing double values accordingly in java

Tags: java, double

I have double values in Java like the following:

```
2.3422
45.3267
25.0
```

What I want to print is:

```
2.34
45.32
25
```

So I used the following method

```
DecimalFormat form=new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
form.format(value);
```

But the problem I am facing is for 25.0 it is printing 25.0 But I want to print 25 only what do i do?

Please note that casting the double value to integer would work for 25.0 but then it would fail for values like 2.3422.

Comment: `45.3267` with 2 decimal places is `45.33`, not `45.32`.

Comment: @Andreas, that depends on the rounding method that is required

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try to use this format: `"#0.##"`

Answer (score 2):

Use this.

```
DecimalFormat form = new DecimalFormat("0.##");
System.out.println(form.format(2.3422));
System.out.println(form.format(45.3267));
System.out.println(form.format(25.0));
```

**output :**
2.34
45.33
25

Answer (score 1):

Fix your code to:

```
DecimalFormat form = new DecimalFormat("#0.##");
```

Or you can either use:

```
double value = 123.456789;
String.format( "%.2f", value );
```

Comment: Doesn't `.2f` produce 2 trailing zeroes?